# Is this Weigela?

Tags: species-identification

A work colleague found this growing in a Northumberland (UK) woodland (May 2018), took a photo and sent it to me.

[image]

It was in an area with non-native species, and this was growing as a shrub. It doesn't spring out as being native to the UK to me?

The leaves are hairy, not waxy. The photo shows a collection of, what I have confirmed, are buds.

If I had to compare it to anything I would say it looks like a Weigela?

Comment: Could you please post a different picture of a leaf and a flower up close and in better lighting? It's really hard to see.  It looks very similar to a bush that grows around there. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's all I was given by a colleague. I'll ask her if she will ever be going to the location again, or can ask another to provide another sample.

Comment: The bush that looks like this one is one of the aronia varieties. If the picture was a bit lighter, I could have compared them better. The only difference is that the regular aronia is a shrub with clusters of berries/flowers, and the bush that grows here is very short and has only a few flowers. But I am sure they are related.